# Laravel generates a folder owned by root, breaks my deployments

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running a Laravel application on Ubuntu 14.04 deploying with deploybot.

Some time after a new deployment, the application generates a folder in /storage/framework/cache/ee owned by root, even though nginx and php is being run on www-data.

This root-owned folder does not allow my deployment user, which is the owner of the parent folder, perform a removal after some deployments, failing new deployments.

I have no idea what this folder is, it contains a folder with random letters/numbers and a file with one line of text in it.

Looking at Laravel documentation, couldn't find it either.

I have no idea what to do next, can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

During your deployment you are likely running any number of `artisan` commands, any one of which could be putting something in cache. If the command line user issuing the command is root, then the file and folder will end up owned by root.

**The quick fix:**

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /storage
```

**Addressing the problem:**

Make sure that when your deploy script (or cron task) calls an `artisan` command it is either

1. called by the user www-data, what I did was `su www-data -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/php artisan heyshoowow"` OR
2. immediately after your artisan calls, redo the above `chown`

Answer (score 0):

Change ownershilp of  your Laravel folder

```
chown -R -f www-data:www-data /path of laravel folder
```